# Tree-like structure to path

Tags: php, loops, tree

I've a tree-like structured array:

```
Array
(
    [dir1] => Array
    (
        [file1] => ...
        [dir2] => Array
            (
               [file1] => ...
               [file2] => ...

        )

    )
)
```

I want to get a pathnames array:

```
Array
(
    [file1] => ....
    [dir2/file1] => ....
    [dir2/file2] => ....
)
```

How could I do that? I've tried with lots of buggy loops and recursive functions, but I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: What do you have so far and how does it fail?

Comment: I like @jeroen think you need to be a little more specific. However, you could learn PHP's built in RecursiveDirectory system and that should accomplish your goals. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple recursive solution would be:

```
function toPathArray($nestedArr) {
    $res = array();
    foreach ($nestedArr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            foreach (toPathArray($val) as $innerKey => $innerVal) {
                $res["$key/$innerKey"] = $innerVal;
            }
        } else {
            $res[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

#### See also:

- [The code in action](http://ideone.com/FJHW7z)

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm!